# How to define SSO exception for a specific user on a specific service provider?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We need to define an exception for a specific user on some of the service providers in SSO configuration via OAuth2.0+OIDC in WSO2 IAMS.

For example, "user1" should can login to SP1 & SP2 service providers using SSO mechanism, but must not login automatically to SP3 & SP4 service providers; while the other users can do.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: You mean, "user1" should not be able to login to SP1 & SP2 completely? And don't you think such restrictions in the direct user level will not scale up?

Comment: "user1" should be able to login to SP1 & SP2 via SSO mechanism, but not to SP3 & SP4.
of course, "user1" can login to SP3 & SP4 as local user (not SSO).

Comment: If this is not a federated login scenario, user will be always be a local user. SSO means once the user logs into one application, he should be able to login without providing the credentials and this does not have anything to do with user being local. I believe you want to force the authentication for certain set of users, while others can login with SSO.

Comment: yes, this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with adaptive authentication.

In the "Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration" sections of the SP, click "Advanced Configuration" and go to the advanced configuration page. Add 2 steps and select "identifier-first" and "basicauth" respectively.

[image]

Add below script in the "Script Based Adaptive Authentication" section.

```
var onLoginRequest = function(context) {
    executeStep(1, {
        onSuccess: function (context) {
            // Extracting authenticated subject from the first step
            var user = context.steps[1].subject.username;
            if (user === "user1") {
                executeStep(2, {
                    stepOptions: {
                        forceAuth: 'true'
                    }, authenticatorParams: {
                        common: {
                            username: user
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    onSuccess: function (context) {
                        Log.info('--------------- step 2 succeeded');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                executeStep(2);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

What it will do is if the username is equal to "user1" it will force the step 2, which is basic authenticator. You can change this condition as you wish.

More info about adaptive authentication can be found from [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/adaptive-authentication/).

Comment: TNX a lot for your comprehensive and beneficial description, Maduranga.

Comment: If you think this will resolve your issue, please consider accepting the answer.